# Как с помощью рефлексии достать поле класса не примитивного типа и не String?

Tags: java

Не очень понял, как можно через рефлексию достать объект, который является полем другого объекта.
Абстрактный пример такой.

```
public class A { 
     B b;
     C c;
     D d;
}
```

Мне нужно получить значение полей объектов b, c, d.
Поля класса A я получаю через `Field[] fields = a.getClass().getFields();` Но вот как дальше я не очень понимаю. Если писать

```
for(Field field : fields)
     field.getClass().getFields();
```

то я получаю поля именно класса Field. Плюс все осложняется все еще тем, что я условно точно знаю, что одно из полей типа B, но я точно не не знаю типы других полей. Т.е. они могут быть C и D, а могут быть E, F.

Answer (score 0):

Метод `Field.getDeclaringClass()` выдает его тип в виде объекта типа `Class`

```
for(Field field : fields) {
     Class declaringClass = field.getDeclaringClass();
}
```